# Elm not able to access the network

Tags: linux, elm, arch

*TL;DR: Everything network-related is working perfectly except one specific binary (in this case - elm).*

I am running a new arch machine - I am connected via wifi and have networks access.
However - elm does not seem to know that. Running `elm make` fails when it tries to download the dependencies. (This is a project imported from somewhere else).

```
I could not connect to https://package.elm-lang.org to get the latest list of
packages, and I was unable to verify your dependencies with the information I
have cached locally.

Are you able to connect to the internet? These dependencies may work once you
get access to the registry!
```

Adding the IP of package.elm-lang.org to /etc/hosts fixes that, but it then throws a similar error for github.com. I can keep doing that, but surely there is a way to convince elm to access the internet.

I'm not using a proxy or anything like that. My connection obviously works and seem stable. `elm init` also fails for the same reasons so i'm unable to test on a brand new directory.

Thank you all for your help :)

Comment: I don't think this is a problem with Elm - it seems that for some reason on your computer running programs in the console (or where ever you run this) don't resolve the Hostnames - maybe you have an issue with your DNS? Does something like `npm` or `git` work (for example does `mkdir Test && cd Test && npm init -y && npm install --save-dev elm` work?

Comment: DNS works fine in every other program (in the terminal and everywhere else)

Comment: Downvoted. This is a configuration question, not a programming question.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently fresh arch uses the `systemd-resolved` daemon for DNS, but elm decides to just read `resolv.conf` directly (which is blank), and then defaults to `127.0.0.1` as the DNS server.

Setting a DNS server manually in `resolv.conf` did the trick.

Comment: glad you could find it - and many thanks for sharing the solution - it's probably gonna effect more Arch users I think

Comment: /etc/resolv.conf should not be blank even when using systemd-resolved. You may want to review https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Systemd-resolved to complete your installation. Do note that by editing resolv.conf manually you change the way systemd-resolved behaves (it will go into client mode). You need to either symlink the systemd-resolved generated resolv.conf to /etc/resolv.conf or use some other daemon to manage your resolv.conf.